# Pi-B Rev 2, Debian - hfsplus: filesystem was not cleanly unmounted - Keys out of order

Tags: debian, mount, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm sorry if I'm not asking to the right thing, maybe you could help.

I've setup my Raspberry Pi B, rev 2 a few months ago, with debian (Linux version 4.4.38+ ) and appletalk, I followed an online guide so that I could setup a time machine backup.

I have mounted an external 500gb drive as /dev/sda2. The drive is several years old. The raspberry PI is several years old too.

I leave the PI on all the time, however after a couple of weeks, I get disk errors. When I run fsck the error is "Keys out of order".

Each time, I have to plug the drive into my mac and use disk utility to repair the errors.

I then need to remount the drive on my pi with :

Sudo chmod 777 /media/tm

and

sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda2 /media/tm

I'm not sure why I'm getting these errors, is the PI or the disk?
Is there anything I can do to prevent these errors?

Comment: Have you tried copying all files to another disk, formatting your disk and then copying all files back?Maybe fsck doesn't really fix the problem.

Comment: I've wiped the disk once

Comment: If the disk keeps on getting damaged, most likely the drive is bad. But other bad hardware (like memory) can also cause such errors to occur. So most likely - a hardware error. Much less likely - some installed app. A Raspberry Pi is not that costly to replace (less costly than a new disk) ...

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking hardware too, but I'd like to identifying which is faulty, no idea where to start.

Comment: You have not stated which filesystem you have on the disk and which hardware you have (to connect it, the disk and the interface). I have bad experience with a WD MyBook, using NTFS over USB3 (on Ubuntu 14.04). I picked out the disk from the MyBook (scrapped that) and mounted it internally in my desktop Linux PC (ext4 fs) and it has worked perfectly since.

Comment: Hfsplus (in title). It's an external drive, I think the pi will be USB 2. I'm not sure about the drive.

Answer (score 1):

"Keys out of order" is a generic error. It points to errors in the sparse bundle and is clear indicator of potential data loss on the disk.

> I'm not sure why I'm getting these errors, is the PI or the disk? Is
>   there anything I can do to prevent these errors?

Most probably these errors are not caused by the Pi, but by Time Machine itself.

If you've run the macOS disk utility before and the corruption keeps coming back, it is recommended to format the drive with your current version of macOS.

If Disk utility can't fix it, you could try more sophisticated tools like Disk Warrior or turn to the terminal. This [blogpost](http://www.garth.org/archives/2011,08,27,169,fix-time-machine-sparsebundle-nas-based-backup-errors.html) describes how to fix Time Machine NAS based sparsebundle backup errors.

The corruption could be caused by uncaught transfer errors using Wifi to backup to the NAS. [Reference](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=93543). There is also mentioned that it might be a good idea to use a USB hub (with PSU) to power the external drive (if it is not powered by it's own PSU).

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit confused by the last link. Is it saying I should have a powered hub in between by external drive and the pi? Currently the external drive has a USB cable hard wired. Incidentally I've got a new drive on order and a USB 3 caddy to put it in.

Comment: Some information there is certainly outdated.

Comment: Do you think a powered USB hub may help?

Comment: It's worth a try but I would not count too much on it.

Comment: OK, I'm now tried a new hard drive and a powered usb hub, things seem fine for a few days, then after a week, the drive become a read-only file system, it hasn't been switched off in this time. So it must be the pi. I guess I've looking at a better device, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The fsck the error `"Keys out of order"` indicates that there is serious error on your filesystem.  If you have any valuable data on it I recommend copying them out.

I recommend doing SMART check via some tool e.g. [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/) to check the disk state.

**EDIT**
For general idea how it should be done:
I would recommend this approach to able to mount the htfplus volume on linux.

a) disable journaling on your drive (on mac) via `sudo diskutil disableJournal volumeName`.  Due to some bug on certain MacOS X you have to enable the journaling before it can be disabled if that is the case please run `sudo diskutil enableJournal volumeName` before and then the `disableJournal` command.

**Note:** Please note that journaling is important part of data integrity and it is there to prevent data loss.  Don't disable it under normal circumstances as it really helps to prevent data loss.

You should have `hfsprogs` install. e.g. for debian `sudo apt-get install install hfsprogs`

then you can try mount it
`sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdX /mnt/mount_point` (or you can try `-o remount,force,rw`).

Then try to re-run the fsck with `sudo fsck.hfsplus -f /dev/sdX` and tell me the result.

Comment: Would the Mac disk utility have done the same thing? I have used that with that disk.

Comment: Which Mac disk utility you have in mind?  If you mean the stock one - ala this `https://macperformanceguide.com/Mac-HowToFailingDrive.html` failing drive then yes.

Comment: Yeah that application

Comment: Go ahead and check it.  Does it give S.M.A.R.T. errors?

Comment: No it didn't produce any errors it couldn't fix. It didn't mention smart errors.

Comment: I see. What kind of distribution do you have on your RPI?  And could you do `diskutil list` on your Mac to see the partitions?

Comment: @Jules please see my edit.